# Scheduler in asp.net core vs T-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am looking for Pros and Cons or a best practice for the following issue that I am having...:

I have built a web site using ASP.NET Core 2.0, using a SQL Server database.

As part of the work, I need to run a background job to check and clean some of the records in my database. I am hesitating between the following:

1. Create a background job in the code, using a scheduler to run this clean up task (let's say a scheduler that will wake up every 15 minutes to run a method in a different thread to do the job).
2. Create a T-SQL that will do the same (using the build in scheduler the db has)

What would you recommend, and why?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it important that you stick to the 15 minute interval? What if you have several background jobs running at once? Can you guarantee that there will only be one web-process running the background job? Running multiple processes (perhaps on multiple servers) will generate multiple background jobs.

Comment: Yes, it should be 15 minutes interval (think of an order that the user places but never completes. This has to be cleaned somehow). I believe making the code right, I will be able to guarantee one thread is up at a time...

Comment: Yes, but what if you need to run your code on two servers for load-balancing purposes? How would you guarantee that _only_ one thread is executing? How do you handle concurrency problems? Or is that irrelevant for this problem?

Comment: I didn't think about it yet. I think it is too early for me to think of load balancing solution to a web site that I am still working on and not sure how much load it will get, but that is a good point. If I'll go with doing that clean up task thru the Web App code, I will definitely that that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

IT Depends on requirement if it needed only cleaning Database data or cleaning cash + db Data.

If we have to clean only Database data and no cleaning of application caching then Job is better option as it is fully managed by database.

If we have to clean application caching + database Data then look for option other that crown jobs here scheduling and other things requires app deployment.

Note: crown jobs externally store next schedule and other detail in Database or File.

Comment: The cleanup process updates some database records. No cache cleaning should occur. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio, create a console application that handles your required tasks.  Build the console application.  Upload the .exe file to Windows Scheduler, where you can schedule tasks to run routinely, easily, and reliably.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my question in this case would be - if I am going with a solution outside of my Web App, why creating another program and not just a T-SQL?

Comment: @YanivAmrami The Console application program should be used to execute the T-SQL or SQL commands/Stored Procedures.  The purpose of this is so you can provide Windows Scheduler with an executable file to operate reliably.